# Can someone explain me this problem?

Tags: functions

If $$f (t) = \dfrac{1000}{1 + Be ^ {kt}}$$ find $f (5)$ given that $f (0) = 20$ and $f (2) = 30$. Hint: $e^{kx} = (e^k) ^ x$

Comment: Please, use descriptive titles "Can someone explain me this problem?" says nothing about the subject of the question, it's useless. Also, you'll get better feedback from users on this site of you show what have you tried to solve the problem, instead of just asking for a solution.

Comment: Here is [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question)

Answer (score -1):

Determine the parameter k and B by setting up and solving the simultaneous equations f(0)=20 (which gives you B) and f(2)=30 (which, knowing B from the earlier equation, will give you k; here you will get an exponential equation so will be probably solved taking log at some point). At this point to find f(5) plug in the B and k found along with t=5.